# How to show a component to full screen?

Tags: angular

I have a button with click event. I need to show a component template in full screen by clicking over the button.

How to do that?

As way I can create component template:

```
<div class="component"></div>
```

And set `position: absolute`.

Then to use:

```
<app-component-fullpage *ngIf="clickeed"></app-component-fullpage>
```

Comment: What is wrong with the question?

Comment: It's not that well formatted and your question is not very clear. That's why people struggle on it

Comment: *What is wrong with the question?* Complete lack of effort, that's what.

Comment: I have described that I tried, it works, but I dont ensure that is right way

Comment: Use position fixed and z-index height.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you add app-component-fullpage to your css

css file

```
app-component-fullpage {
  position: fixed;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100vh;
}
```

you should be close to the solution